# Haskell Non-exhaustive patterns

Tags: haskell

The compiler is telling me that this function has Non-exhaustive patterns, but every scenarios are covered, aren't they?

```
allNeighbors :: Ord v => Graph v -> [v] -> [v] -> [v]
allNeighbors graph (x:xs) neighborsList
                   | length (x:xs) <= 0 = neighborsList
                   | length (x:xs) == 1 = neighborsList ++ (neighbors x graph)
                   | length (x:xs) > 1 = allNeighbors graph xs (neighborsList ++ (neighbors x graph))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not covered: `allNeighbors a [] b`. (Try it; you should get an error.)

---

The `length (x:xs) <= 0` case is unreachable (a list whose first element is `x` cannot have length 0).

`length (x:xs) == 1` is better written as a pattern of the form `[x]`.

`length (x:xs) > 1` is unnecessarily inefficient: It forces the program to walk through the whole list to compute the length, just to see whether there is more than one element. This could be replaced by a pattern like `x : xs@(_ : _)`.

---

In fact, the whole function could be rewritten like this:

```
allNeighbors :: Ord v => Graph v -> [v] -> [v] -> [v]
allNeighbors graph list neighborsList =
    case list of
        []     -> neighborsList
        [x]    -> neighborsList ++ neighbors x graph
        x : xs -> allNeighbors graph xs (neighborsList ++ neighbors x graph)
```

Comment: but allNeighbors a [] b should be covered by : length (x:xs) <= 0?

Comment: @Phil No, because as I wrote in my answer, that case is unreachable. Your base pattern is `allNeighbors graph (x:xs) neighborsList`, and `(x:xs)` doesn't match empty lists.

Comment: @Phil `(x:xs)` matches a non-empty list and binds its head to x and tail to xs.

Comment: I see so that was my error, thanks!

Comment: @Phil: usually I think it is a good idea to compile with `-Wall` or `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` (the former produces more warnings than the latter). In that case the compiler will show you the patterns that are not covered yet by the functions you defined.